# Extract a picture from a Ms word table with java

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

Well, i have a Word with a  presentation text (major step) and a table with 3 column the first one and the second aren't important it's text column, but the third one is complete with some pictures. The purpose is to retrieve the images contained in the third column in order to save them in the database (in BLOB format). I try to solved this problem with Apache POI because I already use it for the other columns where I get the text. Bellow my code already realized :

```
package wordtosql;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.imageio.IIOException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
    import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class ReadDocxTableFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException  {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("FGI-38562 Felsökning låg svetsstyrka CF_UB.docx");

        XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(fis);

        List<XWPFTable> table = docx.getTables();
        for (XWPFTable xwpfTable : table) {
            List<XWPFTableRow> row = xwpfTable.getRows();
            for (XWPFTableRow xwpfTableRow : row) {
                List<XWPFTableCell> cell = xwpfTableRow.getTableCells();
                for (XWPFTableCell xwpfTableCell : cell) {
                    if (xwpfTableCell != null) {
                        System.out.println(xwpfTableCell.getText());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}`

This word is generated by a third party software from which I can exploit nothing but the words it produces. These Word documents are therefore all in the same format.

Comment: As it is .docx it is a zip archive, with content XML and in the media folder the images. So rename .docx to zip and look whether you can find the table cell in XML with geometric info and references to the images. Using a zip file system `jar:file:/... .docx` doing that is relatively simple.

Comment: I read the zip file by exploring its content by hand however I am a beginner in java and I found the images but unfortunately its images are resized in the word I think because for an image in particular I see that part compared to the one retrieved in the media file. does anyone have a track so that I can have the images cropped to the right size?

Comment: One would need to find the table cell in XML where the image is referenced, and explore the attributes for scaling, cropping and such. It might be that this approach is easier or not, but it does not cost much effort. For pretty-printing XML and inspecting one could use a browser.